# PositiveButton e demais botões do alertDialog no android estâo desabilitados, como resolver?

Tags: android, button

Tenho em meu pequeno projeto um `alertDialog`, que é chamado para dar algumas opções ao usuário. Tudo estava funcionando, até que do nada os botões (`positiveButton`, `negativeButton` e `neutralButton`) desabilitaram em todos os meus `AlertDialog` do projeto. O `alertDialog` continua sendo executado, porém os botões ficam em cor mais fraca (típico de quando esta desabilitado) e não chamam os métodos que estão dentro de seus respectivos `onClick();`.

Segue meu código:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();

switch (id) {

    case R.id.generate_pdf_2:
    //Aqui está meu código original, que estava funcionando alguns dias atras.

        /*new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Criando Recibo")
                .setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja criar o recibo?")
                .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(which).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        GeradorRecibo geradorRecibo = new GeradorRecibo(getActivity(), cliente);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recibo gerado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Não", null)
                .show();*/

 //Aqui está uma tentativa que foi o mais parecido com a possivel solução do erro que encontrei, ou seja, segue esta logica porem, obviamente nao é esta a solução pois continua sem funcionar exatamente do mesmo jeito.


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Criando Recibo");
        builder.setMessage("Deseja criar o recibo?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                GeradorRecibo geradorRecibo = new GeradorRecibo(getActivity(), cliente);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recibo gerado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        final Button btn = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        dialog.show();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Testei o código comentado, está correto, porém o código não comentado estava quebrando, assim ele também funcionou bem:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Criando Recibo");
    builder.setMessage("Deseja criar o recibo?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            GeradorRecibo geradorRecibo = new GeradorRecibo(getActivity(), cliente);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recibo gerado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    final Button btn = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    return true;
```

Adicione mais informações, como a versão do Android e mais detalhes do código, isto vai ajudar nas respostas.

Comment: Mas esse código é identico ao do OP. Isso não parece ser uma tentativa de solucionar o problema.

Comment: Não é identico, dialog.getButton() deveria está após a chamada de  dialog.show(), testei na api 23.

Comment: Então pessoal, agradeço os comentarios. Acabei descobrindo o que era. Eram apenas problemas com as permissões, que agora mudaram no android. Acima da api 23 o app devera apresentar para o usuario uma requisição das permissões durante a execução do aplicativo, como as funções do meu alertDialog requerem acesso ao armazenamento interno, foram desabilitados.